# How to send Event to Control in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, events, controls

For example, if i'd like to imitate UIControlEventTouchUpInside for Button1, when Button2 was clicked?
The reason why it isn't enough to addTarget: action:@selector() forControlEvents - is that it's necessary to get default highlight for example (glow effect)

Comment: If you just want the highlight, have you tried setting the "highlighted" property?

Comment: highlighting is just example(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question, +1. I'm still learning & love questions on here that encourage me to go digging around for useful info.

And... here is a cool [Cocoa with Love post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html) about how to synthesize a touch event on the iPhone. You can do that at the co-ords of Button1 when you get the touchUpInside from Button2.